# gRPC server failing on deployment, works from command line

Tags: c#, .net-core, iis, grpc

So I have a pretty basic gRPC server with healthchecks and I am getting errors when I try to deploy it to IIS.
Thing is, when I run it from visual studio or just by executing the .exe generated on build or publish, the server is running and I can call it:
[image]
[image]
[image]

But if I deploy it, then only the /health works and the gRPC calls faills with either (if using secure)
[image]
or (if using non secure)
[image]

This is the **appsettings.json**  that is deployed

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5093"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://0.0.0.0:7243"
      }
    },
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2"
    }
  }
}
```

And this the **launch settings** that VS uses when running from VS:

```
    "XXXX.Server": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5093;https://localhost:7243"
    },
```

The **program.cs** is pretty simple:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Amazon.EventBridge;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using Serilog;
using VSBS.EEM.DataSourceAgentMock.Server.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, logConfiguration) => logConfiguration
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();
builder.Services.AddGrpcHealthChecks()
                .AddCheck("HealthyCheck", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy());
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PublishStatusGenerator>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<AwsPublishWorker>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<CsvDataContentReader>();
builder.Services.AddAWSService<IAmazonEventBridge>();
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGrpcService<InformationModel>();
app.MapGrpcHealthChecksService();
app.MapHealthChecks("/health");
app.Run();
```

I set the application pool to be `no managed code` and well, if it weren't working I couldn't reach the /health endpoint...
So no idea what's going here. I assume it's something related to the http1.1 <-> http2 but cannot figure out what exactly, as it works when debugging/executing directly the .exe

Comment: Does your version of IIS support gRPC (and HTTP/2)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#iis

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, I'm using Windows 11 22H2 22621.2428

Comment: This document is for troubleshooting GRPC on .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-7.0